# Spring MVC- Change/modify Model/Session Attributes dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, servlets

I'm new to Spring MVC and am stuck with the following problem: I have a dropdown list in a JSP which is being populated from an attribute(retrieved from the Model) I've set in the controller. I also have an input box that a user can use to add a new option to the dropdown.

I'm using jquery ajax to send the value entered in the input box to a controller handler, validating it and adding it to the model. Once this is done, I would like the drop down list to be updated with this new value, without the page being refreshed. I realize this can be done by using jquery(adding the updated list to the select element), but would prefer to do this by changing the attribute which is populating the dropdown, if that is possible.

I tried using 'session.setAttribute("mykey","listofvalues") in the controller handler that creates the view and ${mykey} in the jsp select element to retrieve it, all worked fine. I then retrieved the session attribute in the handler that adds a new value to the list. But even after updating the attribute in the controller, the jsp drop down was still displaying the old list.

Am I doing somthing wrong? All I want to do is add new items to a drop down on the same page without redirecting/refreshing the page. Is there anyway to modify a session or model attribute and see the change in a jsp dynamically??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get the desired results by integrating Angularjs with Spring MVC like done here:

http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer has `yes` and a `no`.

> `Yes` You can dynamically change or add or remove values from session object.
>
> `No` You cannot re render the page once it has rendered.

A jsp page is rendered at runtime and then sent back to the client machine. All the renderig has already been done. So even if you change the session data, it will not be reflected till your page is refreshed.

All you can do is send an AJAX call and update the DOM using jquery.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. Just to be sure is there any other way dynamic binding can be achieved so that changes to an attribute in the controller will dynamically reflect in a view?  Any other library/framework that lets us do this at all?

Comment: well none to my knowledge, also it cannot be, since it is server and client side data. any server operation can not change client side code